# References in UML Sequence Diagram

Tags: reference, uml, sequence-diagram

This is my first time creating a UML Sequence diagram. Can you guys help me check if did it correctly?

[UML Sequence Diagram for login process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLNct.jpg):
[image]

[UML Sequence Ref for password authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRrr8.jpg), which is one of the references used in the previous diagram:
[image]

I am confused about the reference part. Can I just redirect to the reference without giving the input data again? Secondly, can the occurrence arrow extends beyond the alt or opt container?

Comment: This is just a blur and not readable. Please provide something that can be read, please.

Comment: @qwerty_so it is indeed blurred pictures. But zooming a little, the ref references mentioned in the text appear readable. The question then made suddenly much more sense ;-)

Comment: @Christophe Either you have eagle's or magical eyes. I can't read it. I'm old and my eyes got worse.

Comment: @qwerty_so not really. My view is not so good. But maybe this is why I can read blurry text as if it was sharp ;-) Here I could read in each of the 3 refs: FiDO authentication, OTP autentication, password authentication.

Comment: I guess it would not ne too much of an effort for the OP to clarify this. In the basic meaning of clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The combined fragment boxes with the operator **`ref`** are indeed references to other interactions. These [**interaction uses**](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#interaction-use) aim to keep complex interaction simpler, by breaking down some parts into separate diagrams.

You can just use the referred interaction (e.g. `password authentication`, `OTP authentication` and `FIDO authentication` in your diagrams), if there's no ambiguity about lifelines. You can also explicitly specify input/output parameters, to "glue" the interaction use with the rest of your SD (see example in the hyperlink). In this case the sequence diagram that is referred to, should in principle define the parameters associated with its name.

It appears that your sequence diagrams are still very complex, despite the ref/interaction uses.  For example, the long succession of `alt` with repeated references suggest an attempt of visual programming with redundant structures that does not make sufficient use of generalisation and scenario techniques.  You should consider therefore further simplification.

P.S: Unfortunately, many parts of the diagrams are very difficult if not impossible to read, so it's difficult to provide more guidance here (prefer PNG format than JPG where the compression can create the blurry effect).